# Problems with XML Schema Nillable

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm new to XML and in trouble validating XML Schema with an instance!

My **XSD**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="result">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="response">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="messages" nillable="true">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="item">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:all>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="date" type="xs:string"/>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="department" type="xs:string"/>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="msg-from" type="xs:string"/>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="reply1" type="xs:string"/>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="reply2" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:all>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My XML **Instance**:

```
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <response>
        <status>No new messages</status>
        <messages xsi:nil="true"/>
    </response>
</result>
```

When I'm trying to validate the instance against the XSD using tools like [this](http://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html), I'm getting following error:

```
cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xsi:nil' is not allowed to appear in element 'messages'.
```

Which I don't understand because I've already put `nillable="true"` for `messages` element!

Your help will be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I figured out that putting `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` in the XML instance validates the XML instance! But the library I'm using is not generating this.

Comment: Ye, you got the namespace wrong. Please answer your question and mark the answer accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that putting `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` in the XML instance validates the XML instance!